# How to use drools in an already existing project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools

I have an eclipse plug-in project and now I want to use drools into it. The examples I have seen in internet is all about creating a drools project from scratch. I don't want to change the folder structure of my existing project. Can you please help me how can I do this ? Drools enforces some folder structure and file location for the rules to get fired, how to achieve this in my existing project ?

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3274906/pottsiex5, I have seen your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743210/integrating-drools-with-a-pre-existing-eclipse-project) on the same topic, but there are no answers. Have you solved it?

Comment: You can't contact users like that. `@` only works for people who have commented/answered the current question.

Comment: Ok :( wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more info on the folder structure you want to retain?

Comment: Hi Neil, as far as I have understood, the Drools rules needs to be under src/main/resource and that is added in classpath as <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>. In my project the class path entry is : <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>. I have some files which I can not move from src folder. That is the problem.                            In short, if it is possible to place the rule files ( .drl) any place in project and use it, then I will be happy. But Drools allows it to do it ? . Kindly let me know if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the eclipse plug-in project structure, but with the help of below code you can load rule files from external location or from classpath

KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

file = "path/to/DRL/file";
resource = kieServices.getResources().newFileSystemResource(file).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
kfs.write(resource);

KieBuilder Kiebuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs);
Kiebuilder.buildAll();